# What camouflage is suitable for air vehicles?

Tags: battlefield-4

I like to ride with tiger camouflage on vehicles, but it is easy to spot. Will i gain something by selecting camouflage? Will vehicle will be harder to spot? (for example, on hardcore, when there is no spot overlay).

What camouflage is better for helicopter or jet?

Will gray or blue camouflage allow me to blend in the sky?

Comment: Camouflage is purely visual aspect. So you can chose whatever you like. The only difference is how the vehicle looks, so indeed, on hardcore it will be harder to spot a vehicle with suitable camouflage for the level

Comment: Well, from inside vehicle it is hard to tell if camouflage is appropriate.

Comment: Step out somewhere and look at it from outside :p

Comment: Your best bet would be to try to match the sky color I guess. Operation Firestorm something more gray would probably be best. I don't think it really matters in most cases though. Helicopter I wouldn't bother, they're pretty loud and hard to miss. Jets are really only hard to see when very high up.

Comment: Camouflage on flying vehicles isn't to hide them from targets on the ground; they will always get spotted, except for maybe at night (and with lack of radar). It is to hide them from other planes. It's easy to spot a plane when you're on the ground, but when you're in another plane, there's lots of other factors that make spotting harder, not the least of which is that you are also going fast -- if two planes fly toward each other, their speed relative to one another is doubled (to a pilot in one of two planes flying towards each other, the other plane seems to be travelling at double speed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward answer is "none". If you look towards the sky you will either see a dark or somewhat light dot in the sky, this will be a jet, most likely. Choppers are too slow to even benefit from camouflage, unless you are so skilled you can hoover-camp in a set area, something that is not wise to begin with.

The thing is that you will constantly be on the move, hence shifting background relatively often, any form of camouflage will then be obsolete. The only thing I can think of is flying at night, then a darker camouflage might be an idea.

If you are on a hardcore server with air, you are likely to find people spawning as engineers with AA loadout, so they can simply swipe across the sky and "see" you once you pass close enough.

For land vehicles, camouflage actually may matter. You can become harder to spot from air, and ground where you can blend in among snowy hills, green grass and tall trees. They need to look twice to notice you if you get a good enough spot.

So in short, when it comes for air vehicles, camouflage patterns are mostly for show, and serves little to no purpose beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

If I can give you and others one good tip. Its not about witch camouflage or vehicle loadout you have but about skill. In non hardcore servers good players will spot you and then camouflage doesn't do much any more.

I like to play hardcore and I must say good camouflage works when you are far away. But still if you stick on to one point on the map you will be noticed. Most enemy players seek revenge after being killed and they will try to find you and of course kill you. Because they know where you approximately are on the map but not exactly where you can reposition and when they come for you kill them again.

Its important that if you use tanks or other armoured vehicles that you stay far away as possible and when the enemy comes to close you must back up. In close combat you are most likely to be killed by engineers with anti tank mines or with bazookas.

In the air you will have no benefit from your camouflage but it can be nice for when you need to land. If you are black or grey a player may notice you and when camouflaged they will most likely just walk by without noticing you. Then you can repair or something in that fashion.

Answer (score 0):

LevelCap posted a Youtube video of his analysis on parachute camos:

Parachute camo isn't exactly analogous to camo for a helicopter or jet, but LevelCap's analysis is relevant since he talks about blending into the sky. He found that Flat Naval blends in best against a solid blue sky:

[image]

He also recommends Spray Urban as a more general choice for a variety of maps, in case you don't want to switch the camo from Flat Naval on a map without a blue sky:

[image]

As the other answers point out, in my experience camo has not been particularly effective at hiding vehicles against a sky background. But if you're looking for even a slight edge your best bets are probably Flat Naval or Spray Urban.